# Change order of posts

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, order, meta-query

I made a post recently that did not explained myself right!
Come again, but with better explanations.

I need the "Select Option" change the order of query_posts.
My current code is:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected">Select order of posts</option>
    <option>Highest price</option><!-- hypercart_meta_price  "order=DESC" -->
    <option>lowest price</option><!-- hypercart_meta_price  "order=ASC" -->
    <option>Discount in%</option><!-- hypercart_meta_discount  "order=DESC" -->
    <option>Release Date</option><!-- date  "order=DESC" -->
</select>
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=products&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_key=hypercart_meta_discount&key=price&cat=' .get_query_var('cat')."&paged=".$paged); ?>
<?php get_template_part("loop-products"); ?>
```

I just need to know how to change the query_posts using the "Select box"
Thank you for understanding. Hug!

**UPDATED MY ISSUE**, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Rudimentary English is fine, but you'll have to add more information, if you want to be able to get a satisfying answer. Show some code - that's universal language anyway.

Comment: Friend, see if you can understand: http://pastebin.com/F7g6LTSm

Comment: This is actually a fairly complex question, with several steps to accomplish (register a query arg, add a query var via user input, and filter the query based on the user-input query var). What have you tried (add actual code to your question), what works, and what doesn't?

Comment: s_ha_dum Updated my friend!

Comment: **Note:** any solution using **`query_posts()`** is *inherently incorrect*. Please attempt an implementation that properly *filters the default query via **`pre_get_posts`***.

Comment: **query_posts** friend worked, the problem now is not the **query_posts** but how to change it to select box, example: customer picks: **Higher price**, ai changes the query_posts for: `<?php query_posts( 'post_type=products&orderby=meta_value_num&order=DESC&meta_key=hypercart_meta_price&key=price&cat=' .get_query_var('cat')."&paged=".$paged); ?>` ... thanks friend. 
Change "**meta_key** AND **order**"

Comment: See this explanation on why not to use `query_posts`: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts#1755 Also, you can post code here... no need to link to pastebin.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem, the solution is in the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/Tu7k3rLb 
Thanks to everyone who helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very detailed. It is hard to work out exactly what you are doing but I am assuming that you are trying to sort posts by a custom meta `meta_key`/`meta_value`. This the formula for that (annotated but basically lifted from the Codex):

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'your_post_type', // I don't know what this is
   'meta_key' => 'your_key', // I don't know what this is
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', // only for numbers; use "meta_value" for alphanumerical keys
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'your_key',
           'value' => array('your_value'), // can be more than one
           'compare' => 'IN', // see the Codex for other values
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

### Reference

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Yes, sorry for not explaining right

An example, the customer selects "High Value" messages appear "higher price" and so with the other options.
I'm trying to solve this day ... :/

Comment: I think this answer still applies.

Comment: Here is an example of the code I have: http://pastebin.com/F7g6LTSm